# Calculating value of Q,when remainder is given. 3rd degree polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

If $f(X) = 2x^3 + 4qx^2 - 3q^2x -2$ is divided by $x-q$ the remainder is $10$, then calculate the value of $q$.

Tried factoring the polynomial.

Obtain quotient by means of long division.

I am truly missing something here. Please help.

Comment: Readers will find it easier to parse your Question if you use [MathJax to express mathematical notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: The polynomial you want to try factoring is $F(x) - 10$.  That is, the remainder of $F(x)$ divided by $x-q$ is $10$ precisely when $x-q$ divides $F(x) - 10$.

Answer (score 1):

Asserting that the remainder of the division of $f(x)$ by $x-q$ is $10$ is the same thing as asserting that $f(q)=10$. So, solve the equation $f(q)=10$.

Comment: This one is the best answer in my opinion.+1

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
f(x) &= 2x^3+4qx^2-3q^2x-2 \\
&= 2x^3-2qx^2+6qx^2-6q^2x+3q^2x-3q^3+3q^3-2 \\
&= 2x^2(x-q)+6qx(x-q)+3q^2(x-q)+3q^3-2 \\
&= (x-q)(2x^2+6qz+3q^2)+3q^3-2 \\
\end{aligned}\end{equation}

Comment: you copied the quadratic term with an incorrect minus sign, the original is $F(X) = 2x^3 + 4qx^2 - 3q^2x -2$